# BATCH: How to capture the extension of the file, or how to do a pattern test like regexp

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm writing a batch file for windows command prompt, I want to loop through files in a directory recursively using FOR /R  *.*
However, inside the loop I want to check if the file of extension .txt or possibly other extensions in order to skip.

How can I do that? in FORFILES there is @ext  what to use with for?

Also, is there something similar to regexp in command prompt?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`%~xV` will expand variable `V` to an extension only. If you think you need regexp, then ditch the batch altogether, and use e.g. Python, otherwise you're only going to be writing unmaintainable mess.

Also, for the love of Cthulhu, console window is not even remotely related to MS-DOS.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Complementing Cat++ answer, for the second question, `FINDSTR` command accepts regular expressions as search strings.

Although it is not a full featured regexp command, for search and replace, it is pretty useful in many simple situations.

Try `HELP FINDSTR`

Or for an introduction and a list of the supported regex expressions by `FINDSTR` see this doc http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx .

Comment: Thanks. i didn't know about findstr. this is really helpful.